# Show all posts using the template page and the loop?

Tags: loop, get-posts

I am trying to make a template page that would display all posts from all categories, in short - every post added to my website. I was googling around and found out that it can be done by using The Loop. The examples were mainly based on Twenty Eleven which is pretty straight-forward. Unfortunately I am using a complex theme and my understanding of PHP is very little... This the website I am developing: http://www.pomorzekultury.pl/ and this is the template page I would like to "adjust" to display everything: http://pastebin.com/5a8fZ3u6 . I hope some of you will make something of this, because as I said eariler I fail understand what is going on here...;)

Edit: The whole code of this PHP file I would like to work on:

```
<?php /* Blog Style B */

        $i = 1;

        if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        $format = get_post_format();
        $cb_meta_onoff = ot_get_option('cb_meta_onoff', 'on');

        $category_data = NULL;

        foreach( ( get_the_category() ) as $category )  {
                        $category_name = $category->cat_name;
                        $category_url = get_category_link($category);
                        $category_data .= '<span class="cb-category"><a href="'.$category_url.'">'.$category_name.'</a></span>';
                        }
        $cat_com_url = get_comments_link();

        $cb_custom_fields = get_post_custom();
        if (isset($cb_custom_fields['cb_review_checkbox'][0])) { $cb_review_checkbox = 'on'; } else { $cb_review_checkbox = 'off'; }
        if ($cb_review_checkbox == 'on') { $format = 'review'; }
        $j = $i / 3;
?>                                       

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="cb-blog-style-b <?php  if (is_int($j)) {echo 'right-half '; } ?>clearfix<?php if (is_sticky()) echo ' sticky'; ?>" role="article">
                <div class="mask">
                <?php cb_review_thumbnail($post); ?>                        
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                      the_post_thumbnail('cb-thumb-350-crop');
                  } else {
                      echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/library/images/thumbnail-350x200.png" alt="related post">';
                }
                ?>
               <?php if (false !== $format) {echo '<span class="cb-icon '. $format . '-icon"></span>'; } ?>
             </a>
        </div>

        <?php echo $category_data; ?>

        <?php if (get_comments_number() > 0) { ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $cat_com_url; ?>">
                        <p class="cb-comments"><?php echo get_comments_number(); ?></p>
                </a>
                <?php } ?>

        <h2 class="h4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h2>

         <?php  if ($cb_meta_onoff == 'on') { ?><p class="cb-byline vcard"><?php printf(__('z dnia <time class="updated" datetime="%2$s" pubdate>%3$s</time>', 'cubell'), cb_get_the_author_posts_link(), get_the_time('Y-m-j'), get_the_time(get_option('date_format')) );  ?></p><?php } ?>

        <div class="cb-excerpt">
            <?php echo cb_clean_excerpt(150, true); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="cb-bottom-white"></div>
    </article> <!-- end article -->

<?php
    $i++;    
    endwhile;  
?>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>    
<?php
      cb_page_navi();                    
    endif;
?>
```

EDIT No.2:

Maybe listing using archives template would be easier? The archive template loads a view template and the code goes like this:

```
<?php get_header(); 
$cb_sidebar_position = ot_get_option('cb_sidebar_position', 'cb_sidebar_right'); 
 ?>

<div id="cb-content" class="wrap clearfix">

    <div id="main" class="<?php if ($cb_sidebar_position == 'cb_sidebar_left'){echo 'left-sidebar';} ?>  clearfix" role="main">

        <?php if (is_day()) { ?>
            <h1 class="archive-title">
                <span><?php _e("Daily Archives:", "cubell"); ?></span> <?php the_time('l, F j, Y'); ?>
            </h1>

        <?php } elseif (is_month()) { ?>
            <h1 class="archive-title">
                <span><?php _e("Monthly Archives:", "cubell"); ?></span> <?php the_time('F Y'); ?>
            </h1>

        <?php } elseif (is_year()) { ?>
            <h1 class="archive-title">
                <span><?php _e("Yearly Archives:", "cubell"); ?></span> <?php the_time('Y'); ?>
            </h1>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) { 

                            get_template_part('cat', 'style-b');
             } ?>

    </div> <!-- end #main -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div> <!-- end #cb-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

so `get_template_part('cat', 'style-b');` is taking care of layout but function/reference to all posts needs to be added... Any ideas? :)

Comment: Please call header and footer part,may be it is possible that global variables are not initiated without header.

Comment: Hi Rafał, are there any filters hooked to pre_get_posts hook in your theme? Could you show us these filters?